# How to run multiple chai assertion in Nightwatch.js using page object?

Tags: automation, ui-automation, nightwatch.js, assertion, pageobjects

In my test I need to verify the same lines of text on multiple pages.
I'm trying to use chai assertion but can't run multiple `.expept` assertion using a page object.

Having two '.expect' assertion fail the test with the error message 
`Unknown property: "expect". Please consult docs at:http://nightwatchjs.org/api.`
when I run it only with one command it runs ok.

```
// Test file code

module.exports = {

    'Copy Test': client => {
    client.url('https://www.testsite.com/')
    client.page.search().checkText()
    client.end();
   },
};
```

```
// Page object file code

let copyP = "Some test text"
let copyP2 = "Some text text 2"

module.exports = {
    elements: {
        p: 'CSS_selector',
        p2: 'CSS_selector',
    },

    commands: [{
        checkText: function() {
            return this 
            .expect.element('@p').text.to.equal( copyP, 'Text is ok')
            .expect.element('@p2').text.to.equal( copyP2, 'Text2 is ok')
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you've detailed is *the correct & desired behavior*.

> Chai's assertions, Nightwatch's built-in assertions, or mostly any
>   other assertions library, *work the same way!* Assertions are ***breaking
>   statements*** (*meaning your program should end execution on one's
>   failure/exception thrown*), with a clear scope & purpose: *evaluating
>   a
>   [predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic))*.
>   Two assertions will always be independent of one another. Thus,
>   there's no logical case concern for chaining two, or more assertions,
>   now is there?

Basically, assertions don't support callback functions, so you cannot pass the result of one to another (*there's no built-in logic for them to do this*).

**So, you can't do this...**

```
browser.click('@someElem')
       .expect.element('@otherElem').to.be.visible
       .expect.element('@otherElem').text.to.equal('I<3Turtles', 'text check');
```

**You can't do this...**

```
browser.click('@someElem')
       .expect.element('@otherElem').to.be.visible
       .setValue('@otherElem', 'I like turtles');
```

... and since we got those out of the way, let's see at how we can refactor that command:

```
commands: [{
    checkText: function() {
        // Perform wrapper for extra safety! 
        this.api.perform((done) => {
            this.expect.element('@p').text.to.equal( copyP, 'Text is ok');
            this.expect.element('@p2').text.to.equal( copyP2, 'Text2 is ok');

            done();
        });
        return this;
    }
}]
```

Comment: This works, thanks @iamdanchiv for your help. It's weird to assume that everyone would need to run only one assertion at a time. In my view it would be nice to make assertions breakable or not somewhere in config file. But there should be a good reason why it works the way it do.

Comment: Well, yes, there is something like that supported by Nightwatch. If you don't want the classical *fail-fast type of assertions*, then you can look at **verify statements** [here](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/#assertions). Those fail as a collection at the end of the test, not breaking the program & runtime. Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Yep, I actually used those assertions, specifically `.containsText()`but I found a bug with it, It doesn't fail if the copy you check is missing the first letter.